# Why does "Brain" print 4 times and not 5 in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm doing some JavaScript koans to learn syntax and I came across one case where I'm a bit confused. This is the code:

```
  it("should know properties that are functions act like methods", function () {
    var megalomaniac = {
      mastermind : "Brain",
      henchman: "Pinky",
      battleCry: function (noOfBrains) {
        return "They are " + this.henchman + " and the" +
          Array(noOfBrains + 1).join(" " + this.mastermind);
      }
    };

    var battleCry = megalomaniac.battleCry(4);
    expect("They are Pinky and the Brain Brain Brain Brain").toMatch(battleCry);
  });
```

Because the battleCry function creates an array with noOfBrains + 1 elements, and noOfBrains is passed in as 4 I would have expected the join() to print 5 "Brain" not 4. Why is it 4?

Thanks!

Comment: because the join delimiter goes between the elements `[1,2,3].join('-')// 1-2-3`. 3 elements, 2 delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an array of size 5 (= 4 + 1). You then join these together.

Note that the `Brain` (the glue) is only applied to the joined parts. As your array is size 5, you need 4 "glue parts" to create a String.

Hence the 4 `Brain`.

If one did something as

```
Array(noOfBrains + 1).map(e => 'Brain').join(' ')
```

you would indeed get 5 items

Comment: Ohhhh, got it. The array has 5 blank objects and it's printing "Brain" in between each of them, right?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it!